# Check whether the conditions for a password are met, but Pearson Revel says it's wrong

Tags: c++, passwords

I am coding a simple program for a C++ homework assignment that requires us to display if a password is valid or invalid based on these 3 conditions:

- A password must have at least eight characters
- A password consists of only letters and digits
- A password must contain at least two digits

When I submit the assignment, it says it contains a logic error. However, I have checked all possible cases for input and my program displayed correctness. Below is my code, can someone point out my mistake?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Please enter a password: ";
    string password;
    cin >> password;

    bool isValid = true;
    if ( password.length() < 8 ) {
        isValid = false;
    }
    else {
        int numberOfDigits = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++ ) {
            if ( !isalnum( password[i] ) ) {
                isValid = false;
                break;
            }
            if ( isdigit( password[i] ) ) {
                numberOfDigits++;
            }
        }
        if ( numberOfDigits < 2 ) {
            isValid = false;
        }
    }
    cout << ( isValid ? "Valid " : "Invalid " ) << "password" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks OK to me. Don't suppose you get more clues as to what went wrong?

Comment: Looks OK to me. The only point I'd make is that `isalnum` and `isdigit` are not defined on negative values, so strictly you should cast to `unsigned char` like this `isalnum( (unsigned char) password[i] )`. I'd be very surprised if that was the issue though.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is correct but the issue is that your not reading past the space in `Pearson Revel`. For this, use `std::getline(std::cin, password);` instead of `cin >> password;`. This should solve the issue.

Note: Still the password is wrong because it passes the first condition, but what about the second and third conditions (take a look at the third).

Also, try not to use `using namespace std;` as its not a good practice. What your doing is taking the whole `std` (which is huuuugeee) namespace and putting it into the global namespace.